# Nested transaction

Tags: jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have the following request:

Transaction A start
...update(1)
Transaction B start
...update(2)
Transaction B end
...update(3)
Transaction A end

Any good idea to let update(2) to become a part of transaction B and commit respectively?
Remarks: I don't use @Transactional, because some rollbacks are needed not only for exceptions.

The transaction B is inside the transaction A. I want to commit update(2) respectively, and when update(3) error happended, rollback update(1) and update(3) only.
I'm using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and set **TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW** and a new TransactionStatus before update(2), but update(2) seems to wait for transaction A reopens.